# Updated way to fix textIO in java for eclipse IDLE

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, import, compiler-errors

I am here trying to fix an error in my IDLEs. I was using eclipse then I switched to IntelliJ but in both, I have the same issue when trying to:

```
import textio.TextIO;
```

I am taking a class and in all the exercises they used textIO; I will need to fix this error to be able to get input from the user in a statement similar to this

```
TextIO.put("Enter your first positive integer: ");
      inputNumber = TextIO.getlnInt();
```

From Eclipse

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    TextIO cannot be resolved
    TextIO cannot be resolved
    at ThreeN1.main(ThreeN1.java:9)
```

From IntelliJ

```
C:\Users\IdeaProjects\ThreeN1\src\com\example\threen1\threen1.java:2:14
java: package textio does not exist
```

Normally I come here as a last resource. I found some similar problems here but they are old from many years ago and much has changed in 5 years.

I would prefer the solution for Eclipse if possible but I am sure one fix would be similar to the other.

Please help me!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you imported the library

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.beryx</groupId>
    <artifactId>text-io</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

[image]

Apply and close.

Then create a class and follow along
[image]

for more on how to use text io .
use their official website https://text-io.beryx.org/releases/latest/

this is the project structure which i've created
[image]

Comment: No. I installed Eclipse last week, this is how new this java thing is for me. I am looking more for a set of instructions on how to fix the issue. The assumption of knowing absolutely nothing is true. How do I import that library and where do I import it to?

Comment: Ok, First create a new java project in eclipse. [File > New > Java Project ]
Since text io is external dependency , you need to import the jar file for it . Had you been using maven for managing depedencies, then the above dependency would have sufficed.  In java project, you need to add the jar file . 
Type on google "text io jar file" and download the jar file, unzip them and then add them to your project build path

Comment: I think the problem with programming languages is not the language itself but the frustration of a non-working IDLE that is supposed to be the easier part. I have spent more time trying to fix the stupid error than doing the work I am supposed to do. I don't understand this.
1. How do I make it a working package or whatever the textIO is?
2. Where do I store it? 
I followed the instructions you send in pictures but mine looks completely different to yours.

Comment: 2) you can store the external jar files whereever you want to . when you click on add external jar, click on the files and they will be added
2. to make a package, right click on src  > new > create new packag and name it.

Comment: My friend. I noticed the project structure is not as you have it in your picture. I guess if I could fix that, maybe the problem would go away. I just need to know how to move those things around. Thanks for your help today.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234192/discussion-between-gurkirat-singh-guliani-and-edy-molina).

Comment: please post another question and explain what is not working so that we can help effectively